# Category related to the fusion category of 2D Ising CFT

Tags: ising-model, category-theory

I am very new to Category theory and would like to better understand the fusion category of 2D Ising CFT, so please forgive my imprecise wordings in this question. I understand that the Ising CFT has 3 simple objects/primaries labelled by {1,$\epsilon$,$\sigma$} with conformal dimensions: (0,0); (1/2,1/2); (1/16,1/16) respectively. The non-trivial fusion algebra is:

$\epsilon^2 = 1, \ \ $ $\sigma\times\epsilon = \epsilon\times \sigma = \sigma, \ \ $ $\sigma^2=1+\epsilon$.

Since this is a diagonal RCFT (rational CFT), one can construct the corresponding Verlinde lines which have the same fusion rules as the primaries themselves. Let me denote these lines as: {1,$\eta$,$N$} where $\eta$ denotes the invertible $\mathbb{Z}_2$-line and $N$ denotes the non-invertible line. Now let me define $N^2\equiv \theta$. My question is, can I interpret {1,$\eta$,$\theta$} with the following non-trivial fusion algebra:

$\eta^2=1, \ \ $ $\eta\times\theta = \theta\times\eta = \theta, \ \ $ $\theta^2 = 2\theta$,

as a fusion sub-category of the Ising category? If not, does the above form a category by itself? If yes, what is this category called. My confusion is since $\theta=N^2$ is not a simple object, I am not sure how to interpret the above "apparent" category. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a complete answer, but I can say that the "category" you're considering, with simple objects $\{1,\eta,\theta\}$ is not a fusion category because $\theta$ doesn't have a simple object which fuses with it to yield the identity object as a term in the sum:
$$1\times\theta=\theta\times 1=\theta,\quad\eta\times\theta=\theta\times\eta=\theta,\quad\theta\times\theta=\theta+\theta.$$
I believe this is required at the level of fusion rings by the definition of the identity element combined with Frobenius reciprocity. I think the categorical version of this statement is that a fusion category is rigid, so every simple object has a dual simple object, but perhaps someone with more math background can come behind and elaborate.

For more discussion of this, see Section 8.2-8.3 of [Topological Quantum: Lecture Notes
and Proto-Book](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/topological2020/TopoBookOct27hyperlink.pdf) by Steven H. Simon and [AnyonWiki](https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/Concepts/FusionRing.html).

EDIT: According to AnyonWiki, the Ising fusion ring only has one subring, namely $\mathbb{Z}_2$, see [here](https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/FRPages/FR_3_1_0_1.html).